# Sqoop Import from MySql failed with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: mysql, import, hdfs, sqoop

Importing data from MySQL `sqoopdb` to HDFS from table `employee` 

**Commands** 
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoopdb --username sqoop -P --table employee`

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoopdb --username sqoop -P --table employee --m 1`

**Both generate the below error:**

```
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
2019-03-24 16:08:19,779 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
Enter password: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.validateHiveOptions(BaseSqoopTool.java:1583)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.validateOptions(ImportTool.java:1178)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:137)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 8 more`
```

Comment: Hello, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting, because simply dumping a bunch of code isn't very popular and probably won't give you an answer

Answer (score 5):

Download and copy the `commons-lang-2.6.jar` to `/usr/local/sqoop/lib` folder and `import` will work fine.

I am using `Hadoop - 3.2.0` and `Sqoop 1.4.7`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoopdb --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username sqoop -P --table employee --m 1
```

Also make sure you have granted the access for this database using

```
% mysql -u root -p 
Enter password:
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sqoopdb.* TO ''@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> quit;
Bye
```

Comment: The actual problem here is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`. I guess this has nothing to do with MySQL db connection.